# Splitting Interfaces And implementations into separate Modules/JARs

Tags: java, api, maven, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am building a component that does some tax calculations. I have created two Maven modules `tax-utility-api` and `tax-utility-impl`.

`tax-utility-api` contains interfaces for the component

> public int getTaxableIncome(int income);

and `tax-utility-impl` contains the actual implementations

> public int getTaxableIncome(int income){
>
> // some code
>
> }

The reason why I split the interfaces and implementations into different JARs was so that other components will depend only the `api`(contract) JAR to develop code at their end. And the `impl` JAR will be required only during runtime.

But as I tried to create a test component that depends on this component's `api` JAR, I realized that I am not able to use the functions as they are interfaces and not concrete methods. So instead depending on the `impl` I am able to use component's functions.

That has confused me now and I have two questions:

1. Firstly, to make other components just depend on the interfaces in my `api` JAR do I need a DI framework like Spring?
2. Did I misunderstood the real benefit/purpose of splitting the interfaces(contract) and implementation into different modules/JARs?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should be testing the implementation classes *in the `impl` module* and mocking the interfaces when unit-testing classes that consume the API. (Spring is in fact great for this sort of thing, but it's not necessary for these tasks. At runtime you will need *some* code with responsibility for DI, whether that's Spring, Guice, or your own launcher.)

Comment: @chrylis I am not able to understand your point . Can you share a short example.